# Creating a partial that can take a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I'm having a problem with a partial that displays takes in a collection of @users, and then creates a report like:

_users.html.erb:

```
<table>
<tr>
...
</tr>
<% @items.each do |u| %>
..
<% end %>
</table>
```

So now in my home#index erb page, I want to display 2 reports like:

```
But I am getting an error saying that items doesn't exist.

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I tell the partial that @good_users or @bad_users is to be assigned to @items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a local variable, like 'users'

```
<table>
<tr>
...
</tr>
<% users.each do |u| %>
..
<% end %>
</table>
```

And when you're rendering the partial, set the local variable:

```
render partial: 'users', locals: { users: @good_users }
```

or

```
render partial: 'users', locals: { users: @bad_users }
```

as appropriate.